# read input csv file from apache flink application in docker container

Tags: docker, input, filesystems, apache-flink

I have an apache flink application created with maven that reads data from a csv file and creates a datastream. the code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
        input = params.get("input");

FileReader filereader = new FileReader(input);
```

when I test it in IntelliJ everything works, but when I run the Jar file in the job manager using the command:

```
./bin/flink run -c test1.RollsCount ./examples/project1.jar --input ./examples/dataset.csv
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

So it seems like the application can not read the file, which is located in the file system as shown below:

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

I tried to change the code writing the file path in the java code as follow:

```
Reader filereader = new FileReader("/opt/flink/examples/dataset.csv");
```

but this time I have the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/flink/examples/dataset.csv (No such file or directory)
```

so it looks like I am not writing correctly the path but looking on internet it looks correct.

---

UPDATE

so I did a lot of testing and it looks like if the filereader is in the main method it works.

if it is, like in my case in a separated class it does not recognize it.

any suggestion?

Comment: If you running Flink in Docker container probably it's just Docker looking for the path inside a container and not knowing about host machine filesystem. [about docker workdir](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-workdir-command-in-docker)